# WCF-Capturing the full HTTP response

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using WCF to call a method on a Java web service (using `basicHttp` with `<security mode="Transport">`).  The service returns some HTML back instead of a SOAPFault.  WCF seems to implement some odd truncating of the content returned in the exception, so I can't see the entire error.

Is there a way to get the entire response?  Perhaps some configuration I can change to pull back more then 660 bytes?  I tried turning on service tracing, but it doesn't seem to capture the entire response.  I'm unable to use **Fiddler** or **Charles**, because the service is using two-way SSL and it's on a secure network.  Here's the exception:

`The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 660 bytes of the response were: '<html><head><title>Server - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </he`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an exception occurred on the server side. When exception occurs with httpBinding,  HTTP status becomes 404 - NotFound.

It might be as a result of:

1. Incorrect signature of calling method and actual method, or order of parameters
2. Failure to serialize or deserialize the result
3. Some failure with SSL configuration/keys
4. Internal exception within WCF

In order to eliminate all the above try connecting to it using plain .NET client without SSL. Then add a level of complexity each time.

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Have you set IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = True in ServiceDebugBehavior?
That might help.

Comment: I'm not hosting a WCF Service... just using WCF has the client to connect to a Java Service.

Comment: I see. But why not just try to solve the problem by using the correct binding as the exception suggests, instead of trying to get the rest of the response?

Comment: Just because before you know how to set correct binding you have to know what mistake you did in current configuration. Such information can be in that resposne.

Comment: Seems to me that in this particular case the relevant information is already at the start of the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to capture outgoing SOAP request and send that request through HttpWebRequest class. This should allow you capturing whole response.